# SignalR message size performance implications with Redis backplane

Tags: c#, .net, performance, redis, signalr

How important is message size to the performance of SignalR with Redis backplane?

I'm sending JSON over SignalR. The application servers are easily replicable to divide load but the Redis backplane is a single instance. There are two options:

1. Send just an id. The client then makes a HTTP request to the server based on the id to get the latest data. The size is approximately 30 bytes (JSON with a single field).
2. Send the desired information in the payload of the message. Thus, there is no need for the client to make a follow-up HTTP request. The size of the largest messages is approximately 2kB (JSON with 50 fields, some of which are nested).

The purpose of option 1) would be to lessen the load on the backplane and direct it elsewhere. To warrant this, would the message size significantly affect the message throughput in a single instance of Redis backplane?